# How to make a secondary navbar using Bootstrap that's conditional on the first?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started experimenting with Bootstrap.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

- I have a primary navbar at the top, which I've custom styled, using Bootstrap's navbar functionality.  Main links such as Home, About Us, Contact, etc...
- For certain tabs in the primary navbar, I want a secondary navbar to be spawned underneath the primary navbar with "sub links" (ex. About Us might have different pages for History, News, etc...)

Is there a way to do this using Bootstrap?  The only basic functionality I see is having two navbars of identical styling, that are always present.

A good example can be found here: http://newrelic.com/about, where if you click on the About link at the top, a secondary navigation bar is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Just give the secondary navbar a class (such as 'no-show') which sets the display property to none:

```
.no-show { display: none; }
```

Then, when the about link is clicked, toggle the class:

```
$('#about').click(function(e) {
    $('#nav_secondary').toggleClass('no-show');
});
```

Here's a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/7MY9v/8/). You'll have to add some css to style and position the navbar the way you want.